# an error occurred while loading the page, reloading. Only occurring on certain pages

Tags: html, ios, iphone

I have recently begun development on a jewelery store website and have been getting errors on certain pages when opening on the iPhone. The error is "A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded". I do not receive this error on Android or Windows phones. I do not get the error when using chrome IOS either, only Safari. This only occurs on certain pages.For example if I am to open [Bottoni Jewelers Home Page](http://www.bottonijewelers.com) I do not receive this error, but if I navigate to [Brand page for Bottoni Jewelers](http://bottonijewelers.com/cj_jewels.php) it will get the error and force multiple reloads until it just gives up and stops loading. I have been unable to determine what is the cause of this issue. My code is below, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I have tested all of the code and this snippet below seems to be what is causing the issue, as when I remove it I no longer receive the error.

```css
#brand_intro {
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
.officina {
 text-align:center;
 border-bottom:2px solid #B7886E;
 padding:15px 0 20px 0;
}
.brand_sections {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #CDAC9A;
}
.brand_images {
 max-width:400px;
 height:auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div class="container-fluid officina">
  <div class="container">
   <img class="cj_logo" src="assets/cj_jewels_white.png" alt="CJ Jewels Collection" title="CJ Jewels Collection"/>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-4 col-lg-4 brand_display no-border">
     <img class="brand_images" src="assets/cj_jewels/goldring_3.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-4 col-lg-4 brand_display no-border">
     <img class="brand_images" src="assets/cj_jewels/engagement.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-4 col-lg-4 brand_display no-border">
     <img class="brand_images" src="assets/cj_jewels/engage_weddingband_1.jpg"/>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-4 col-lg-4 brand_display no-border">
     <img class="brand_images" src="assets/cj_jewels/engage_weddingband_2.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-4 col-lg-4 brand_display no-border">
     <img class="brand_images" src="assets/cj_jewels/engage_weddingband_4.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-4 col-lg-4 brand_display no-border">
     <img class="brand_images" src="assets/cj_jewels/engage_weddingband_5.jpg"/>
    </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-4 col-lg-4 brand_display no-border">
     <img class="brand_images" src="assets/cj_jewels/engage_weddingband_6.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-4 col-lg-4 brand_display no-border">
     <img class="brand_images" src="assets/cj_jewels/engage_weddingband_7.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-4 col-lg-4 brand_display no-border">
     <img class="brand_images" src="assets/cj_jewels/engage_weddingband_8.jpg"/>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Again, thank you in advance for any help or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a closing <\div>, I've seen weird things happen when the formatting isn't right. 
Could you try changing that?